# Aspnet Zero Nswag generating service proxies

Tags: c#, angular, aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I am using Aspnet Zero they generating service proxies in typescript using NSWAG. Now I want to generate these service proxies separately in every single file. Any idea of how to achieve it?

Comment: Hello, you can follow this issue on Github about it: 
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1398

Comment: @JoséPolanco thanks for your time. I have got great help from the provided link.